# Genomic relationship matrix explanation

Tags: ngs, genomics

I am seeking the definition of the genetic distance matrices used in genomic prediction.

- What is the difference between a Rodger distance and kinship matrix?
- what people mean when they talk about genomic relationship matrix as in this paper:
  https://www.g3journal.org/content/9/5/1545#ref-30 , viz.

> then we obtained the Cholesky decomposition of the genomic
> relationship matrix

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question (and the answers) in the biology community: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/35330/59521